# SSL_connect() fail on WinCE 5.0

Tags: c#, vb.net, openssl, compact-framework, windows-ce

I used OpenSSL 1.0.2j to develop a desktop email client application with no 
problems. I copied the code from my desktop to a WinCE 5.0 device .NET CF 2.0. 
The connection SSL_connect() alway fails with a value of 5 (SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL). 
A call to CE's GetLastError() on gives me an error 10038 (WSAENOTSOCK Socket operation on nonsocket). 
Do you have any suggestions? what might be causing this problem?

Thanks in advance

Here's the code:

```
        SSL_library_init() 
        OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf() 
        Dim sslCtx As IntPtr = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method()) 
        Dim ssl_socket As IntPtr = SSL_new(sslCtx) 
        Dim sbioPtr As IntPtr = BIO_new_socket(mySocket.Handle, 0) 
        SSL_set_bio(ssl_socket, sbioPtr, sbioPtr) 

        Dim connOK As Integer = SSL_connect(ssl_socket) 
        If connOK = 1 Then 
          ..... 
        Else 
             MsgBox("OpenSSL's SSL_connect() failed") 
            Dim errcode As Integer = SSL_get_error(ssl_socket, connOK) 
               MsgBox("SSL Error: " + errcode.ToString) 
            If errcode = 5 Then 
                MsgBox("GLE = " + Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error.ToString) 
            End If 
        End If 
        mySocket.Close() 
    Else 
        MsgBox("Socket's connect() failed") 
    End If
```

Comment: The error is at SSL_set_bio(ssl_socket, sbioPtr, sbioPtr) . a) missing code, b) used .net wrapper c) SSL recompiled for WinCE? You can not use the same code for desktop and WinCE (except for simple stuff).

Comment: Thanks!  I recompiled OpenSSL for both platform desktop and winCE device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Socket's handle create using CompactFramework on WinCE has always value greater than Int (max value expected on ' *BIO_new_socket* ')